# Why sprank(A) and A\b report different rank in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a point set P and I construct it's adjacent matrix A by k-nearest neighbor. Each row of A is [...+1...-1...], indicates a pair of neighbor points. The size of A is 48348 x 8058, sprank(A) is 8058. But when I do the following, it gives me a warning: "Warning: Rank deficient, rank = 8055, tol =  8.307912e-10."

a=A*b;
c=A\a;

and norm(c-b) is quite large. It seems something is wrong with the adjacent matrix A, but I can't figure it out. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sprank` only tells you how many rows/columns of your matrix have non-zero elements, while `A\b` is reporting the actual rank of the matrix which indicates how many rows of your matrix are *linearly independent*. For example, for following matrix:

```
A = [-1  1  0  0;
      0  1 -1  0;
      1  0 -1  0; 
      0  0  1 -1]
```

`sprank(A)` is 4 but `rank(A)` is only 3 because you can write the third row as a linear combination of the other rows, specifically `A(2,:) - A(1,:)`.

The issue that you need to address is either in how you're computing `A` (if you expect that to generate a system of linearly independent equations) or you need to find a way to use `A` that doesn't require factorizing a rank deficient matrix.

Comment: Thanks! In my problem, the matrix A tends to be ill-conditioned, so I'm using LSQR(http://www.stanford.edu/group/SOL/software/lsqr.html) so solve the sparse linear equations.